# Cloudwego Kitex/Hertz debugging

Tags: go

I need to set up and run [hertz](https://www.cloudwego.io/docs/hertz/) and [kitex](https://www.cloudwego.io/docs/kitex/) servers. I've run the commands
`go mod tidy`
`go run .`
i get this errors. However, these errors are generated by the imported links itself and not within my code. Is there a method to circumvent this? Other netpoll versions (netpoll@v0.3.2) have no errors.

```
# github.com/bytedance/gopkg/util/xxhash3
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash.go:78:26: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash.go:97:26: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash.go:124:24: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:115:29: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:142:76: prime64_2 (untyped int constant 14029467366897019727) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:149:31: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:190:82: prime64_2 (untyped int constant 14029467366897019727) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:202:27: prime64_1 (untyped int constant 11400714785074694791) overflows uintptr
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\gopkg@v0.0.0-20230531144706-a12972768317\util\xxhash3\hash128.go:203:29: prime64_2 (untyped int constant 14029467366897019727) overflows uintptr
# github.com/bytedance/sonic/internal/rt
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\sonic@v1.8.8\internal\rt\int48.go:25:28: MinInt48 (untyped int constant -140737488355328) overflows int
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\bytedance\sonic@v1.8.8\internal\rt\int48.go:25:44: MaxInt48 (untyped int constant 140737488355327) overflows int
# github.com/cloudwego/netpoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\net_io.go:22:48: undefined: syscall.Iovec
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\net_io.go:23:11: undefined: readv
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\net_io.go:36:48: undefined: syscall.Iovec
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\net_io.go:37:11: undefined: sendmsg
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:17:10: undefined: defaultPoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:23:10: undefined: defaultPoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:27:10: undefined: defaultPoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:33:10: undefined: defaultPoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:39:10: undefined: defaultPoll
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\poll_default.go:55:33: undefined: barrier
..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\cloudwego\netpoll@v0.4.0\net_io.go:37:11: too many errors
```

I have tried to reinstall Go, redo my code but there seems to be some error with the github generated code.